# How to version Drupal with Git?

Tags: git, github, drupal, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal, it's quite obscure to me and there are a few points I'd like you to help me with.

I've read somewhere that "sites/default/files" should be a part of .gitignore.
When I installed Drupal the only differences in the project were the new folder "sites/default/files" containing among others a "config_xxx" folder, and the settings.php, in "sites", setting the DB parameters and the config directories mentionned above.

When I manually remove the "default/files" folder and go on drupal, it's been created again, but only with php files. So no css, for instance. I suppose it's what will happen if I don't commit this folder.

I tried to commit it anyway, to clone it and to run the cloned project (same db, same everything). It did not work, it seemed to have no css either, while this time, the "sites/default/files" exists and (theoretically) contains the same things than the initial project.

Well, actually it has now several new files in the "php/twig" folder, files with another prefixe than files that have been commited from the initial project. So I guess that guy was right, one's not supposed to commit this folder.

So, how ? Can you guys, tell me what's the standard way of sharing a drupal project with git ? Let's say I simply want to run drupal website, exactly as it is just after the installation, but on another computer (but same db, of course). How should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 7 is storing user uploaded files in `/sites/default/files` . That's the reason why you shouldn't add that dir to git. But if it don't belong to GIT it doesn't mean that you should delete that dir. Not sure if D8 is storing uploaded files at same place, but generally speaking, files uploaded by users should not be added to GIT repo.